# Inner product doesn't matter for Schur orthogonality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm reading Knapp's *Basic Algebra*, specifically the section about Schur orthogonality relations. Given a representation $R: G \to \text{End}(V)$, he defines $V_R$ to be the vector space of *matrix coefficients*, i.e. functions $G \to \mathbb{C}$ of the form $g \mapsto \langle R(g)v_1, v_2 \rangle$ for some $v_1, v_2$, and for some inner product w.r.t which the representation is orthogonal.

He comments that that $V_R = V_{R'}$ if $R'$ is an equivalent representation to $R$. I believe the proof is that if $\phi:(R,V) \to  (R',W)$ is an invertible $G$-equivariant map, then we have 
$$
\langle R(g) v_1, v_2 \rangle_V = \langle R(g) \phi^{-1}(\phi(v_1)), v_2\rangle_V = \langle \phi^{-1}(R'(g)\phi(v_1)), v_2\rangle_V \\
= \langle R'(g)\phi(v_1), (\phi^{-1})^*(v_2) \rangle_W, 
$$
so an $R$ matrix coefficient with vectors $v_1, v_2$ is an $R'$ matrix coefficient with vectors $\phi(v_1), (\phi^{-1})^*(v_2)$.

Just want to make sure I understand this: we could just take $W$ to be $V$ with a different inner product, so $V_R$ doesn't depend on the inner product being such that $R$ is unitary, right? And orthogonality should hold for any functions $g \mapsto \langle R(g)v_1, v_2 \rangle$, with any inner product?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "orthogonality"? Many things tend to go under that name. But $V_R$ is indeed the same for all nondegenerate bilinear or sesquilinear forms $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ on $V$ (at least if $V$ is finite-dimensional).

Comment: OK, so Proposition 7.22 (a) in Knapp should hold for any bilinear or sesquilinear forms instead of the two forms $\left(\cdot, \cdot\right)$ (once the typo "$v_1,v_2 \in V_1$" is corrected to "$v_1,v'_1 \in V_1$"). Why? Because if you have a nondegenerate bilinear form $\left(\cdot, \cdot\right)$ and an arbitrary bilinear form $\left[\cdot, \cdot\right]$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then there exists an $A \in \operatorname{End} V$ such that every $v, v' \in V$ satisfy $\left[v, v'\right] = \left(v, Av'\right)$. This allows you to easily ...

Comment: ... obtain the generalized Proposition 7.22 (a) from the original Proposition 7.22 (a) (at least once you have restated my claim for sesquilinear forms, which I cannot be bothered to do). A similar trick should work with Proposition 7.22 (b).